# Cyberark: Check whether the account password is static or dynamic

Tags: cyber-ark

How can we tell this is a dynamic or static account?

Comment: What do you mean by static/dynamic account? What you selected is usually used for LDAP accounts, LINUX/UNIX accounts, etc.

Comment: @Alex_P CyberArk is a password vault. You need to create an account for every password that you want to store. I'm storing an LDAP account password for a bot here for example. The passwords/accounts can be static/dynamic or even manual.

Comment: I am pretty familiar with CyberArk but there is no such thing as static or dynamic accounts. You were asking is whether password management is enabled. Furthermore, you wanted to know about the one-time password setting. In this case you phrased your question wrong as you did not mention any of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution:
One should look into the platform details by clicking the little search icon below the password reset box: